# How to control the order of sections in MSVC x86 compiled binaries?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, portable-executable

For some very low level application I require to have the entry point as the lowest/first item in the binary.

To do this I've done the following:

Placed the entry point in "function_ordering.txt" and passed it to the /ORDER linker option.

Generated a map file to see the following sections exist:

```
 Preferred load address is 00040000

 Start         Length     Name                   Class
 0001:00000000 000210fdH .text$di                CODE
 0001:00021100 002d7b0cH .text$mn                CODE
 0001:002f8c10 00027874H .text$x                 CODE
 0001:00320490 0000830fH .text$yd                CODE
 0002:00000000 000005d8H .idata$5                DATA
 0002:000005d8 00000004H .CRT$XCA                DATA
 0002:000005dc 00000004H .CRT$XCAA               DATA
 0002:000005e0 00000004H .CRT$XCL                DATA
 0002:000005e4 00001554H .CRT$XCU                DATA
 0002:00001b38 00000004H .CRT$XCZ                DATA
 0002:00001b3c 00000004H .CRT$XIA                DATA
 0002:00001b40 00000004H .CRT$XIAA               DATA
 0002:00001b44 00000004H .CRT$XIC                DATA
 0002:00001b48 00000004H .CRT$XIY                DATA
 0002:00001b4c 00000004H .CRT$XIZ                DATA
 0002:00001b50 00057fb8H .rdata                  DATA
```

And that WinMain was AFTER this data. So I figured I need to put the function in its own section to make it "first".

So I put it in its own section:

```
#pragma code_seg("test")
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    return 0;
}
```

But this put the function even further away! This is because my test section appeared after the other sections.

So then I did this:

```
#pragma code_seg(".text$di")
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Which resulted in:

```
  Address         Publics by Value              Rva+Base       Lib:Object

 0000:00000000       ___guard_fids_count        00000000     <absolute>
 0000:00000000       ___guard_flags             00000000     <absolute>
 0000:00000000       ___guard_fids_table        00000000     <absolute>
 0000:00000000       __except_list              00000000     <absolute>
 0000:00000ec7       ___safe_se_handler_count   00000ec7     <absolute>
 0000:00009876       __ldused                   00009876     <absolute>
 0000:00009876       __fltused                  00009876     <absolute>
 0000:00000000       ___ImageBase               00040000     <linker-defined>
 0001:00000000       _WinMain@16                00041000 f   lol.obj
```

BOOM it worked. But this seems very much like a nasty hack.

So the question is.. is there a "supported" or "documented" way to get my section to appear first?

Comment: I hate to break the bad news, but the entrypoint is not actually WinMain.  For this program it is WinMainCRTStartup.  Which initializes the CRT, then calls WinMain.  If you override that with the linker's /ENTRY option then you are running a program without correctly initialized runtime support.  Which includes not getting proper initialization of your own code.  Many problems, much sorrow.  Avoid XY questions.

Comment: Ah yes I did realize that, I suppose I should call out "WinMain" rather than "Entry point"

Comment: I noticed some close votes are building up. Anyone care to explain whats wrong with this question?

Comment: Besides which function is the real entrypoint, I think its a very interesting question.  The fact that you got your function to the top of the section and it wasn't the real entrypoint is pretty nifty so no doubt if you weren't using the CRT you'd have no problem getting the real entrypoint to the top.  I'm pretty sure using the linker flags as you did is the proper way to do what you're doing.